# ObservableCollection not update TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I don't understand why my TreeView not update using a ObservableCollection.

Main Window

```
 public ObservableCollection<Student> listStudents { get; set; }



    internal MainWindow(List<Student> list, Controller controller)
    {         
        this.listStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>(list);
        this.controller = controller;

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

XAML

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tv_source" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ListStudents}" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
```

I add a child like this :

```
public void addChild(TreeViewItem _sourceItem, TreeViewItem _targetItem)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ((Student)_targetItem.DataContext).Phones.Add(_sourceItem.DataContext.ToString())));
        }
```

Student class

```
public class Student
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Phones { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: If you are adding a `string` to the `Phones` property and data bind against this collection, you should change its type to `ObservableCollection<string>` for the added `string` to show up in the UI. Now it seems to be a `List<string>`.

Comment: Is ListStudents defined with starting letter in lower case (listStudents) or is just a typing error? -> ItemsSource="{Binding ListStudents}" inside the class is defined public ObservableCollection<Student> listStudents { get; set; }

Comment: @mm8 thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a string to the `Phones` property and data bind against this collection, you should change its type to `ObservableCollection<string>` for the added `string` to show up in the UI. Now it seems to be a `List<string>`.